# How do I separate two divs containing images that are stacked on top of each over in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, html, alignment

I'm creating a hover animation for the images in my portfolio and so far I've adapted two images to test the animation out. The position of the animation during hover still needs changing I know but the problem is, the two images seem randomly stacked on top of each other and nothing I try to do can get them unstacked. Here's the HTML:

```
<!--raw-->
<div style="text-align:center;">
<div id = 'day3' src ="http://rowanibbeken.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10    /IMGP1222.jpg" style="border: 5px solid white; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">
<div id = 'overlayday3' style='left: 295px; top: 829px; position:absolute;' src = 'http://rowanibbeken.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Overlay-Image.png'></div>
<div id = 'day4' src ="http://rowanibbeken.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/IMGP1243-3-small.jpg" style="border: 5px solid white; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">
<div id = 'overlayday4' style='left: 600px; top: 829px; position:absolute;' src =    'http://rowanibbeken.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Overlay-Image.png'></div>
</div>  
<!--/raw-->
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#day3 {
width: 368px;
height: 245px;
border: 5px solid white;
background-image: url('http://rowanibbeken.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/IMGP1222.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
}

#day4 {
width: 368px;
height: 245px;
border: 5px solid white;
background-image: url('http://rowanibbeken.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/IMGP1243-3-small.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
}

#overlayday3 {
width: 101px;
height: 245px;
display: none;
transform: rotate(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
background-image: url('http://rowanibbeken.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Overlay-Image-very-small.png');
}

#overlayday4 {
width: 101px;
height: 245px;
display: none;
transform: rotate(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
background-image: url('http://rowanibbeken.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Overlay-Image-very-small.png');
}

#overlayday3:hover {
width: 101px;
height: 245px;
background-image: url('http://rowanibbeken.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Overlay-Image-on-Hover-very-small.png');
}

#overlayday4:hover {
width: 101px;
height: 245px;
background-image: url('http://rowanibbeken.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Overlay-Image-on-Hover-very-small.png');
}

#day3:hover > #overlayday3 {
display: inline-block;
}

#day4:hover > #overlayday4 {
display: inline-block;
}
```

And here's the page in question: http://rowanibbeken.co.uk/?page_id=22

I know this  is a lot of code but I would really appreciate any help as nothing I've tried seems to work. 
Thanks a lot!
Rowan

Answer (score 0):

It appears the reason is that you have the `day4` div inside of the `day3` div. Take it out and see what happens